# Azure ML LibraryExecutionError Missing Features

Tags: python-3.x, azure, machine-learning

I am facing a similar issue. In my case, I have provided all the required fields with values. But still it, I am getting this error:

```
{'error': {'code': 'LibraryExecutionError', 'message': 'Module execution encountered an internal library error.', 'details': [{'code': 'ScoredFeaturesMustMatchTrainingFeatures', 'target': 'Score Model (AFx Library)', 'message': "table: The data set being scored must contain all features used during training, missing feature(s): 'Value_Date_Day', 'Value_Date_month', 'Value_Date_year', 'Cost_Center'."}]}}
```

I have even tried recreating the whole model again but still the issue persisted.

Please explain why we are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't found any answer why this issue is appearing. But below alternatives can be tried for model creations.

1. Try to avoid blocks which will create additional columns. Eg Use label encoding instead of the dummification.
2. Use Azure Automate ML for model creation, but is paid service

Thanks